# Powershell script to compare folder structure

Tags: powershell, directory, compareobject

I m trying to write a powershell script which will check the folder structure for a directory against a template folder structure layout and report back if its different i.e folders missing or different folders added.

```
Folder Template Structure
Folder A
Folder B

Directory 1 to check
Folder A
Folder B
Folder C

Directory 2 to check
Folder A
```

So for Directory 1 it would report Folder C is additional and for Directory 2 it would report Folder B is missing

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Get the directories inside the template dir. as relative paths
$templateDirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Name $templatePath

# Ditto for directory 1 and directory 2
$dir1Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Name $dir1Path
$dir2Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Name $dir2Path

# Compare to the template dirs.
Compare-Object $templateDirs $dir1Dirs
'---'  # Output separator string just to show distinct outputs.
Compare-Object $templateDirs $dir2Dirs
```

Note the use of `-Name` with `Get-ChildItem`, which causes all subdirectories (`-Directory`, `-Recurse` to be reported as *paths relative to the input directory*, which allows convenient comparison between directory trees.

Also note that the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet by default outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances with two properties, and only for *differences* between the input sets:

- `.InputObject`, in your case a relative directory path that is unique to one input set.
- `.SideIndicator`, which is a string indicating whether the input object was unique to the *left* side (the *first* input set, implicitly bound to parameter `-ReferenceObject`) - `'<='` - or to the *right* side (the *second* input set, implicitly bound to parameter `-DifferenceObject`) - `'=>'`

The above yields something like:

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
C           =>             # folder C only in dir. 1, not in template dir.
---
B           <=             # folder B only in template dir., not in dir. 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two folders, perform the following steps (from: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/08/easily-compare-two-folders-by-using-powershell/ ):

1. Use the Get-ChildItem cmdlet with the recurse switched parameter and
   the path parameter (points to the folder to use for reference) to
   obtain a collection of fileinfo objects. Store these objects in a
   variable.
2. Use the Get-ChildItem cmdlet with the recurse switched parameter and
   the path parameter (points to the folder to use for comparison) to
   obtain a collection of fileinfo objects. Store these objects in a
   different variable.
3. Use the Compare-Object cmdlet and specify the objects stored in the
   first variable to the ReferenceObject parameter. Supply the objects
   stored in the second variable to the DifferenceObject parameter.

Code:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\fso

$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\template

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

Comment: This won't work robustly, because `Compare-Object` compares the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects by their `.ToString()` value, which in Windows PowerShell is the _mere filename_ in this case.
To truly compare two folder trees, you must compare their items by their _relative paths within the subtree_.