# Comparing two folder structures with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, compare

I am trying to compare two folder structures with PowerShell. At the end, I should see an overview of all files/folders with the full path, which are just in folder A or folder B.

I also want to implement a switch which can be toggled to exclude the file extensions.
The comparison should just be done at the path level. So when a file has the same name but a different size, it should be seen as "equal".

So far, it looks like this:

```ps1
# Prompt for the paths of the two folders to compare
$folder1 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder A"
$folder2 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder B"

# Prompt for whether to ignore file extensions
$ignoreExtensions = Read-Host "Ignore file extensions? (y/n)"
$ignoreExtensions = $ignoreExtensions.ToLower() -eq "y"

# Get the files in each folder and store their names and paths in arrays
$dir1Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name $folder1 | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    if ($ignoreExtensions) {
        $name = $name -replace '\.[^.]*$'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $name
        FullName = $_.FullName
    }
}
$dir2Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name $folder2 | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    if ($ignoreExtensions) {
        $name = $name -replace '\.[^.]*$'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $name
        FullName = $_.FullName
    }
}

# Compare the two arrays of file names and display the paths to files that are different
$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dir1Dirs -DifferenceObject $dir2Dirs | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }

if ($diff) {
    Write-Host "Files that are different:"
    $diff | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
} else {
    Write-Host "No differences found."
}
```

but I get an error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> D:\compare4.ps1
Enter the path for Folder A: D:\folder1
Enter the path for Folder B: D:\folder2
Ignore file extensions? (y/n): y

Files that are different:
Select-Object : Property "FullName" cannot be found.
At D:\compare4.ps1:36 char:13
+     $diff | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{InputObject=; SideIndicator==>}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumen
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Select-Object : Property "FullName" cannot be found.
At D:\compare4.ps1:36 char:13
+     $diff | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{InputObject=; SideIndicator==>}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumen
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

When change the compare line from above with this one, the error is gone, but no output generated:

```ps1
$diff = Compare-Object $dir1Dirs $dir2Dirs -Property Name -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare folder trees by the *relative* paths of the files in them.

While [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem)'s `-Name` parameter does output relative paths, it is *all* that it outputs, i.e. it emits *strings* rather than the usual [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) (and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)) instances, which means that the output won't have properties such as `.FullName`

*If* the requirement to optionally ignore extension weren't in the picture, you would be able to *reconstruct* the original full paths, by *inferring* what root path to prepend, depending on the value of `.SideIndicator` in the output from [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object).

To satisfy your requirements, you'll have to:

- Add a `.RelativePath` property to the `[pscustomobject]` instances you construct, and manually determine the relative path, by removing the *root* path's substring from the `.FullName` property of each file.
- Compare the arrays of custom objects by that property, using `-Property RelativePath`. Additionally, in order to ensure that your custom objects are *passed through as a whole*, you must add `-PassThru`

To put it all together:

```bash
$folder1 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder A"
$folder2 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder B"

# Prompt for whether to ignore file extensions
$ignoreExtensions = 'y' -eq (Read-Host 'Ignore file extensions? (y/n)')

# Get the files in each folder and store their relative and full paths
# in arrays, optionally without extensions.
$dir1Dirs, $dir2Dirs = $folder1, $folder2 | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $fullRootPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $_
    # Construct the array of custom objects for the folder tree at hand
    # and *output it as a single object*, using the unary form of the 
    # array construction operator, ","  
    , @(
      Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath $fullRootPath |
        ForEach-Object {
          $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($fullRootPath.Length + 1)
          if ($ignoreExtensions) { $relativePath = $relativePath -replace '\.[^.]*$' }
          [PSCustomObject] @{
            RelativePath = $relativePath
            FullName = $_.FullName
          }
        }
    )
  }

# Compare the two arrays.
# Note the use of -Property RelativePath and -PassThru
# as well as the Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' filter, which
# - as in your question - only reports differences
# from the -DifferenceObject collection.
# To report differences from *either* collection, simply remove the filter.
$diff = 
  Compare-Object -Property RelativePath -PassThru $dir1Dirs $dir2Dirs | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'

# Output the results.
if ($diff) {
    Write-Host "Files that are different:"
    $diff | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
} else {
    Write-Host "No differences found."
}
```

Note:

- The use of `, @(...)` to ensure that the `Get-ChildItem` output objects are output as an array *as a whole* (a single object) is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375).

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation. Two things: 1) As long as in folder 2 more files are then in folder 1, everything works fine. If in folder 1 are more files, these files are not mentioned as difference. I also noticed, empty folders are not recognized as being different. 2) What if I would like to integrate the option that empty folders also show up as difference?

Comment: @x0100, re 2): If you want to include empty directories that have no counterpart in the respective other directory tree, remove the `-File` option from the `Get-ChildItem` call.

Comment: @x0100, re 1): To report differences from _either_ input collection, remove the `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'` filter - I only included it  because your code in the question has such a filter.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing two things in your code.

1. When using `Compare-Object` you also need to provide the `-Property` to indicate which property value to check.
2. When using `Get-ChildItem` you was using `-Name` property, which is not going to work.

Here is the updated code:

```
# Prompt for the paths of the two folders to compare
$folder1 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder A"
$folder2 = Read-Host "Enter the path for Folder B"

# Prompt for whether to ignore file extensions
$ignoreExtensions = Read-Host "Ignore file extensions? (y/n)"
$ignoreExtensions = $ignoreExtensions.ToLower() -eq "y"

# Get the files in each folder and store their names and paths in arrays
$dir1Dirs = Get-ChildItem $folder1 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    if ($ignoreExtensions) {
        $name = $name -replace '\.[^.]*$'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $name
        FullName = $_.FullName
    }
}
$dir2Dirs = Get-ChildItem $folder2 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    if ($ignoreExtensions) {
        $name = $name -replace '\.[^.]*$'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $name
        FullName = $_.FullName
    }
}

# Compare the two arrays of file names and display the paths to files that are different
$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dir1Dirs -DifferenceObject $dir2Dirs -Property FullName | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }

if ($diff) {
    Write-Host "Files that are different:"
    $diff | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
} else {
    Write-Host "No differences found."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking, but it is not quite there yet. A quick test didn't bring up the results I expected, but I will take a closer look later on this.

Regarding the -Name and Get-ChildItem, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693701/powershell-script-to-compare-folder-structure) that this combination will cause all subdirectories -Directory, -Recurse to be reported as paths relative to the input directory, which allows convenient comparison between directory trees.

Or did I miss understand something?

Comment: Taht's correct, if you use `-Recurse`, it will show all subdirectories recursively